# What are my options for feeding fairly static data to a react frontend?

Tags: reactjs

I have some data that I retrieve from a third party and cache client-side. What are my options for feeding this data to my react front-end?

Some options I've thought of:

- Including data in a `<script>` tag
- Including a file that gets read by the js
- Attaching data in a cookie
- Feeding the data in with AJAX
- Feeding the data in with websockets

Of these five, just tossing the data into a cookie and reading it seems the most straightforward and easiest to implement. Not sure how other people are feeding fairly static data to react front-ends when AJAX and websockets are overkill.

Comment: What kind of static data do you have? JSON, images ...?

Comment: Really vague question... but the latter two options definitely seem more viable than the others you listed.

Comment: don't forget localstorage/sessionstorage, it's easy as using cookie